# Coq destruct with an excluding precondition

Tags: coq

I'm learning Coq with the [softwarefoundations book](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/toc.html) and got stuck on the last task in the [induction chapter](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Induction.html) - Exercise: 5 stars, advanced (binary_inverse) part c.

Given the next defenitions.

```
Inductive bin : Type :=
  | Z
  | B0 (n : bin)
  | B1 (n : bin).

Fixpoint norm_bin (input :bin): bin :=
  match input with
    | Z => Z
    | B0 Z => Z
    | B1 restInput => B1 (norm_bin restInput)
    | B0 restInput=> match norm_bin restInput with
      | Z => Z
      | _ => B0 (norm_bin restInput)
    end
  end.
```

I'm trying to prove

```
Theorem norm_bin_B0_out : 
  forall b, norm_bin b <> Z -> norm_bin (B0 b) = B0 (norm_bin b).
```

**I tried to `destruct b`, but can not solve the case `b = Z` according to the condition `norm_bin b <> Z`, `b` can not be `Z`. How can I prove it?** Thanks in advance!

Thanks to the reply below I managed to prove it this way:

```
Theorem norm_bin_B0_out : 
  forall b, norm_bin b <> Z -> norm_bin (B0 b) = B0 (norm_bin b).
Proof.
  intros b H.
  simpl.
  destruct norm_bin eqn:f.
  - simpl in H. tauto.
  - simpl. destruct b.
    { discriminate. }
    { reflexivity. }
    { reflexivity. }
  - destruct b.
    { discriminate. }
    { reflexivity. }
    { reflexivity. }
Qed.
```

I didn't know that norm_bin can be destructed. That was a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a hypothesis `H` that is a negation (for instance `~A`), but you know you can prove the negated formula (you can prove `A`), then the good step to perform is `case H`, this leads to a goal where you do have to prove `A`.

After checking that this is not an exercise in the SF book, I have decided to help you some more.

The formula in your statement `norm_bin (B0 b)` is eligible for symbolic execution computation by the `simpl` tactic.  Do that.

After this step, you see an expression that contains 2 match statements.  One of these is a match statement on `b`, the other is a match statement on `norm_bin b`.  Your next step can then be a `destruct` on `b`, but it can also be a `destruct` on `norm_bin`.  try both routes, but if you choose the latter, use the `eqn:`
variant of the `destruct` tactic.

If you prefer that your next step is a destruct on `b`, the problem is that you get an expression with `norm_bin` applied to `(B0 (B0 ...)`.  Using `simpl` on a goal with this formula will lead to too much computation.  You will need to tame this by using `change` instead of `simpl` and writing yourself what you think would be the best intermediate computation for your needs.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply! It helped to solve the case b = Z, but i still can not prove norm_bin_B0_out.